# internal reconstruction before comparative method

Tags: reconstruction

I am just curious about the comparative method, and how a simple tool could be so powerful. So, I want to ask if internal reconstruction could be applied to the oldest IE languages (Pre-Latin, Pre-Sanskrit, etc.) to reconstruct Proto-Indo-European. So, here is what I was thinking:

attested languages -> unattested pre-attested language -> proto-language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and internal reconstruction has been used to great effect in IE studies.  Saussure's laryngeal theory was discovered using internal reconstruction, at a time when no direct reflexes of the laryngeals were known.  Later, reflexes in Hittite were discovered, showing that internal reconstruction was a valid method.  See [laryngeal theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laryngeal_theory).